# ckeditor insert image style error

Tags: html, css, image, tags, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor on my site, and when I add an image, it generates this code:

```
<img alt="" src="somelink" 194px;="" height:="" 74px;"="">
```

So the `img` tag does not have a height and width. What can I do to do it correctly?

Comment: Which version of CKEditor are you using?

Comment: What is the actual `src` value?

Comment: Reworded for clarity.